# Rearrange a dataframe into a matrix based on column values in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a dataframe with three columns: values, type and class.

It looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(value = c(1:10), type = c("a","b","c","a","b","b","c","a","b","b"), 
                 class = c("aos","aos","ezx","ezx","kl","kl","wq","wq","us","us"))

    
value  type class
    1   a   aos
    2   b   aos
    3   c   ezx
    4   a   ezx
    5   b   kl
    6   b   kl
    7   c   wq
    8   a   wq
    9   b   us
    10  b   us
```

I want to rearrange it into a matrix where the columns represent the different type values and the rows the class values, and where the intersecting values are the mean value of the original data from the dataframe.

The matrix I am looking for should look like this:

```
   aos   ezx    kl   wq     us

a    1     4          8
b    2         5.5         9.5
c          3          7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `tapply` from `base R` to return the structure

```
with(df, tapply(value, list(type, class), FUN = mean))
#  aos ezx  kl  us wq
#a   1   4  NA  NA  8
#b   2  NA 5.5 9.5 NA
#c  NA   3  NA  NA  7
```

---

Or with `pivot_wider` making use of `values_fn`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = class, values_from = value, values_fn = mean) %>% 
  column_to_rownames('type') %>%
   as.matrix
#  aos ezx  kl wq  us
#a   1   4  NA  8  NA
#b   2  NA 5.5 NA 9.5
#c  NA   3  NA  7  NA
```

Comment: Or `tapply(df$value, df[c("type","class")], mean)` as a variation.